# cron job in php to hit over 100 dynamic url's to cache pages

Tags: php, curl, cron, wget

We're using a back-end proprietary database to feed data to over 100 dynamic pages on our website.  The URL's are in the form www.example.com/blah?id=1, www.example.com/blah?id=2, etc.  These pages can take up to 5 seconds to load since the retrieval of data is so slow (because of the database we're connecting to).

My goal is to write a cron job (in PHP), that will "loop" through and make a request to all of our dynamic pages so they are cached (we have a 24 hour cache for these pages).

Is my best approach a PHP script with embedded "wget" commands where the output is ignored?  I have access to cURL if that is preferred.  Is there a performance issue with writing a script that will hit 100 URL's just to cache the pages?  We'll of course run it off peak hours at night.

Thanks for any guidance on this one!

Comment: It depends on your servers horse power. Will 100 concurrent requests all regenerating cache files hurt? It would cleaner to run a cronjob to do this all server side...

Comment: At 100 URLs at 5 seconds, it'll take about 8.3 minutes to loop through all of your pages. I doubt that this would cause any performance issues to loop through the pages overnight. However, is the reason that data retrieval slow a factor of bandwidth, or do queries need to be optimized, etc. It might be good to figure that out too!

Comment: Thanks, guys.  The performance issue is with the queries that are retrieving the data.  The database we're using (old and built in-house) slows down significantly when you query multiple tables, which is what we're having to do.  Before we completely re-write everything and switch to a "real" database, the band-aid fix plan is to "wget" the 100 URL's to load them into a 24-hour cache.  The requests won't be concurrent, I'll do them one at a time in a loop.  I was hoping to find some "starter" code as an example, something that utilizes wget or curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using multi-cURL to get this done.  That way, your requests will run in parallel to each other.

You can do this with the [built-in PHP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php), but I suggest using one of the many classes that wrap them:

https://github.com/jmathai/php-multi-curl

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/multi.html

Comment: Cool, I'll check that out thanks.  I only need to make the request and ignore anything come back from the call.  I assume there's a way to run the curl request silently or to drop the output similar to how you can pipe wget calls to /dev/null.  I'm less familiar with curl, but I'll figure it out.  Thanks!  :)

Comment: @scottystang, Yeah, just don't do anything with the output.  I see now that you're actually querying your own servers with this, and you have some bottleneck on your DB end.  If that is the case, do not request all 100 URLs at the same time.  A simple `foreach` loop will work fine for you.

Comment: Cool, sounds good.  Is there a way via cURL to ignore the output?  I'll write a loop that builds the URL's dynamically, each time calling a cURL request, but I need to ignore the output each time.

Comment: @scottystang, Like I said before, just don't do anything with the output.